# Two templating engines in one nodejs server

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have downloaded hackathon starter boilerplate for nodejs. The templating engine in it by default is pug and it is getting difficult for me to write my html in pug so i tried adding `consolidate` in app.js file and then added another engine 'html'.

But i am trying to add a href link in pug file to my html file so that i can add fucntionality in it but adding just the href link in pug gives me `call back function required error`.

Please tell me what would be the most effectie way for that either i remove all the pug files and use html engine as default and create all pages again that are already in boilerplate or add another templating engine html and if it is the latter then how can i create the link between these files?

pug file

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 Athlete Training System
  //- p.lead A boilerplate for Node.js web applications.
  hr
  .row
    .col-md-6
      h2 Heading
      p Welcome to Athlete Training System platfomr. Here you can have manage your team and keep a look at all players in the team.
      p
        a.btn.btn-raised(href='addPlayer.html', role='button') View details »
    .col-md-6
      h2 Heading
      p Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
      p
        a.btn.btn-raised(href='#', role='button') View details »
```

app.js file

```
* Module dependencies.
 */
const express = require('express');
const compression = require('compression');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
const flash = require('express-flash');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const expressStatusMonitor = require('express-status-monitor');
const sass = require('node-sass-middleware');
const multer = require('multer');
var engines = require('consolidate');

const upload = multer({ dest: path.join(__dirname, 'uploads') });

/**
 * Load environment variables from .env file, where API keys and passwords are configured.
 */
dotenv.load({ path: '.env.example' });

/**
 * Controllers (route handlers).
 */
const homeController = require('./controllers/home');
const userController = require('./controllers/user');
const apiController = require('./controllers/api');
const contactController = require('./controllers/contact');

/**
 * API keys and Passport configuration.
 */
const passportConfig = require('./config/passport');

/**
 * Create Express server.
 */
const app = express();

/**
 * Connect to MongoDB.
 */
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(err);
  console.log('%s MongoDB connection error. Please make sure MongoDB is running.', chalk.red('✗'));
  process.exit();
});

/**
 * Express configuration.
 */
app.set('host', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '0.0.0.0');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
// app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', engines.html);
app.use(expressStatusMonitor());
app.use(compression());
app.use(sass({
  src: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
  dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
}));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(session({
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  cookie: { maxAge: 1209600000 }, // two weeks in milliseconds
  store: new MongoStore({
    url: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
    autoReconnect: true,
  })
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.path === '/api/upload') {
    next();
  } else {
    lusca.csrf()(req, res, next);
  }
});

/**
 * Error Handler.
 */
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  // only use in development
  app.use(errorHandler());
} else {
  app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  });
}

/**
 * Start Express server.
 */
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log('%s App is running at http://localhost:%d in %s mode', chalk.green('✓'), app.get('port'), app.get('env'));
  console.log('  Press CTRL-C to stop\n');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: The pug file is irrelevant to your question, you will need to post your app.js/server.js file instead.

Comment: @Graham okay i have added app.js file too now :)

Comment: Please read this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve then edit your question down to the relevant parts of your app.js.

Comment: @Graham can you check this now?

Comment: In my opinion you should choose one rendering engine or the other.  There are both technical and organizational reasons that make this a bad idea.  To put it another way, if I inherited an app that had two rendering engines it would be my top priority to refactor the app to only use one.